# When stickyHeaderIndices is used, style of component changes

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-scrollview, react-native-stylesheet

I've searched common problems and how to use `stickyHeaderIndices` and so on. But stuck with one point, and I didn't even find why this occurs, so couldn't search on the internet.

Everything works fine on web, but not on my phone when I use sticky.

My Scroll View Structure:

```js
<ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} style={styles.layout}>
    <View style={styles.topBar}>
       <Text style={styles.title}>Messages</Text>
       <View style={styles.notificationIcon}>
          <Text style={styles.notificationIconTxt}>{notificationCount}</Text>
       </View>
    </View>
    <ChatItem pairingCategory={'Name'} />
</ScrollView>
```

View that I want to stick on top:

[image]

If I use the structure above, it sticks on top but style of the component changes (as in the picture below), I want that bubble to stay next to text.

[image]

Here's my styles:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    layout: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: colors.lightBg
    },
    topBar: {
        backgroundColor: colors.lightBg,
        paddingVertical: 15,
        paddingLeft: 24,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'nowrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
        marginRight: 8,
    },
    notificationIcon: {
        borderRadius: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: colors.mainBg,
        padding: 5
    },
    notificationIconTxt: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: "700"
    }
})
```

Whenever I delete `stickyHeaderIndices`, topBar view seems the way I want, but not sticks to top.
Why it happens, and what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I still don't know, what was the reason for it, but created new component called `ChatListTopBar` then wrapped my first children View.

```js
function ChatListTopBar({notificationCount}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.topBar}>
            <Text lineBreakMode='false' style={styles.title}>Mesajlar</Text>
            <View style={styles.notificationIcon}>
                <Text style={styles.notificationIconTxt}>15</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

```js
//ScrollView section seems so
<ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} style={styles.layout}>
   <ChatListTopBar notificationCount={notificationCount} />
   <ChatItem pairingCategory={'Name'} />
</ScrollView>
```

Replacing like so, just fixed the issue!

Answer (score 2):

wrap your View which you are trying to stick with <></>