# How do you make the SecondCard of a React Native FlatList sticky?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using `FlatList` in `React-Native`.

Inside `FlatList` are 3 Box's (Box1, Box2, Box3). When structured like this, I want to make Box2 a Sticky element.

How should I do this?

I'll write down what I tried below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const data = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
//...etc
];

const App = () => {
  const renderVerticalItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={[...data]}
      renderItem={renderVerticalItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => `vertical_${index}`}
      stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    height: 56,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your View which you are trying to stick with <></>

```
const App = () => {
  const renderVerticalItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  };
```

And you can be referenced with `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980766/when-stickyheaderindices-is-used-style-of-component-changes`